# Custom plugin activation error

Tags: plugins, plugin-development

I am having this error and I cannot understand where the problem is.

I am learning plugin development and I am trying to create an OOP plugin to facilitate myself during development.

When I try to activate my custom plugin I get this error:

[image]

What I am doing wrong?

-- Main plugin file --

```php
defined('ABSPATH') or die('(ಠ_ಠ)┌∩┐ NOPE!'); // or any other WP related stuff like add_action

if (file_exists(__DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php')) {
  require_once(__DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php');
}

function activate_oop_plugin(){
  \WPlugin\Core\Activate::activate();
}
register_activation_hook(__FILE__, 'activate_oop_plugin');

function deactivate_oop_plugin(){
  \WPlugin\Core\Deactivate::deactivate();
}
register_deactivation_hook(__FILE__, 'deactivate_oop_plugin');

\WPlugin\Init::register_services();
```

-- Activate file --

```php
namespace WPlugin\Core;

use WPlugin\Controllers\BaseController;

class Activate extends BaseController
{

  public static function activate()
  {
    flush_rewrite_rules();

    $default = array();


    if (!get_option('test_plugin')) {
      update_option('test_plugin', $default);
    }

    if (!get_option('test_plugin_cpt')) {
      update_option('test_plugin_cpt', $default);
    }
  }
}
```

-- Deactivate file --

```php
namespace WPlugin\Core;

class Deactivate{
  public static function deactivate(){
    flush_rewrite_rules();
  }
}
```

Comment: Did you rename `activate_oop_plugin()`? The error message implies that you had named it `activate_plugin()`.

Comment: Yes I renamed it from ```activate_plugin()``` to ```activate_oop_plugin()``` to see if that was the error, but it is not that. I still get the above error even after renaming the function.

Comment: It is definitely what caused the error. Error messages like this are very specific, and you're not going to get that error unless you've named that function that name on that line of that file. If it's still happening there might be some sort of cache at play, in which case I'd suggest renaming the plugin as a way to try and get around it.

Comment: Yes Jacob it solved the problem, but there was even another error caused from wrong namespaces that were reverted by VS code at random to an old one.

Comment: If there's another error then you should include that in the question. I'm not sure what you're asking for here?

Comment: No worries I was asking for anything, I was just pointing to the fact that while solving the above error I found another one and fixed it :). You have been very helpful, thanks a lot.